# Any vim plugins to integrate git status for each file in file window explorer?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, git, plugin-fugitive

is there any vim plugins could show git status for each file in file window explorer?

Please notice that I am not asking integrate git status in statusline, but in file explorer like nerdtree/defx, etc.

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic here. Instead, please [edit] your question to be about solving a specific problem (NB: a plugin may make a great answer to such a question).

Comment: Yeh, well sometimes rules don't make much sense. The answer can't be anything else than a plugin. How do I do this using a plugin?